# requestLocationUpdates permission

Tags: android, permissions, location, locationmanager

I have an Android application that sends **GPS** location to a **DB**.
I tested it today and found that the **location manager** needs permission to call `requestLocationUpdates`.

I want to set permission on allowed and I don't want to ask the device or the user for permission.

[image: call requires permission which may be rejected by user...]

Now, the code requires to add some code to ask for permission?

```
     /**
     * Enable location services
     */
    public void connect() {
        Log.d(TAG, ".connect() entered");

        // Check if location provider is enabled
        String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationProvider)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Location provider not enabled.");
            app.setCurrentLocation(null);
            return;
        }

        // register for location updates, if location provider and permission are available
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        if (bestProvider != null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, Constants.LOCATION_MIN_TIME, Constants.LOCATION_MIN_DISTANCE, this);
            app.setCurrentLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disable location services
     */
    public void disconnect() {
        Log.d(TAG, ".disconnect() entered");

        String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationProvider)) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }
```

I have added   to manifest too.
PS: This permission is newly required because I have been testing the app days ago on the same device ( Android 4.4) and it worked well.
Is it possible that some default permission on Android has changed since 2017/08/21? If so how can I change it?

Comment: *I want to set permission on allowed and I don't want to ask the device or the user for permission.* too bad, what you want is impossible

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman I ve added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write a method to check whether permission is given by user. If not then ask user for permission.
Constants.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST is just requestcode to match when got callback in onRequestpermission result

```
public static boolean checkLocationPermission(Activity activity){
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, Constants.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

As the user allows, you will get callback on overridden method "onRequestPermissionsResult()"

Comment: I think this is useful for me. Can you please tell me what is "WaselGiftConstants" ?

Comment: can you explain the request code more I cann't resolve it on my app. do you have any idea that can help. Thank you

Comment: @ch.ihssen I think this link will help you better... :-) https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#handle-response

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask for permission on run time from Marshmallow version of android. Go through this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

We use following code to check for location permission:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
```

Comment: yeah I am asking about this code actually. My device is API 17.

Comment: how can you explain the fact that it was working properly few days ago on my device.

Comment: May be you have changed `buildToolsVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` or `compileSdkVersion`

Answer (score 0):

It is the best library to check permissions
**com.github.fccaikai:AndroidPermissionX:1.0.0**

Example code:

```
final PermissionCompat.Builder builder = new PermissionCompat.Builder(activity);

    builder.addPermissions(new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    });

    builder.addPermissionRationale(activity.getString(R.string.permission_rationale));

    builder.addRequestPermissionsCallBack(new OnRequestPermissionsCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onGrant() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Grant");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDenied(String permission) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Denied");
        }
    });

    builder.build().request();
```

Comment: I want to get GPS location not Camera

Comment: This is only example. Change them to your permissions.